# Angular update ng-repeat based on model in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angular. i am trying to display a list of brands using ng-repeat. it is working fine. but when i click next button it should also change accorading array index. it is not working for me. please help me resolve this isssue. and tell best way structure this type of case. my code is below

var data = [{"Measure":"Measure1","Flavours":[{"FlavourName":"flavourname1","TotalBrands":[{"BrandName":"Brand1"},{"BrandName":"Brand2"}]},{"FlavourName":"flavourname2","TotalBrands":[{"BrandName":"Brand3"},{"BrandName":"Brand4"}]}]}];
var myApp = angular.module("survey",[]);

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="survey">
        <div ng-controller="DataController">
            <button ng-click="getPreviousFlavour()">Previous</button>
            <p>Flavour Count {{flavourCount}}</p>
            <p>Measure : {{surveyList[measureCount].Measure}}</p>
            <p> Flavours Name : {{flavours[flavourCount].FlavourName}}</p>
            <p>All Brands</p>
            <div ng-repeat="brand in totalBrands">
                <p>{{brand.BrandName}}</p>
            </div>
            <button ng-click="getNextFlavour()">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

    myApp.controller("DataController",['$scope',function($scope){
$scope.name = "sajid";
$scope.measureCount = 0;
$scope.flavourCount = 0;
$scope.surveyList = data;
$scope.listLength = $scope.surveyList.length;
$scope.flavours = $scope.surveyList[$scope.measureCount].Flavours;
$scope.totalBrands = $scope.flavours[$scope.flavourCount].TotalBrands;


$scope.getPreviousMeasure = function(){
    if($scope.measureCount === 0){
        $scope.measureCount = 0;
    }else{
        $scope.measureCount = $scope.measureCount - 1;  
    }
};
$scope.getNextMeasure = function(){
    if($scope.listLength-1 === $scope.measureCount){
        $scope.measureCount = 0;
    }else{
        $scope.measureCount = $scope.measureCount + 1;  
    }
};

$scope.getPreviousFlavour = function(){

    if($scope.flavours === 0){
        $scope.measureCount = $scope.measureCount - 1;
        $scope.flavourCount = 0;
    }else{
        $scope.flavourCount = $scope.flavourCount -1;   
    }
};

$scope.getNextFlavour = function(){
    if($scope.flavours.length  === $scope.flavourCount){
        $scope.measureCount = $scope.measureCount + 1;
        $scope.flavourCount = 0;
    }else{
        $scope.flavourCount = $scope.flavourCount + 1;  
    }

};
```

}]);

Comment: sorry could not add sample data to code section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line in getPreviousFlavour and getNextFlavour you should insert

```
$scope.totalBrands = $scope.flavours[$scope.flavourCount].TotalBrands;
```

This renews totalBrands.

```
$scope.getPreviousFlavour = function(){

    if($scope.flavours === 0){
        $scope.measureCount = $scope.measureCount - 1;
        $scope.flavourCount = 0;
    }else{
        $scope.flavourCount = $scope.flavourCount -1;   
    }
    $scope.totalBrands = $scope.flavours[$scope.flavourCount].TotalBrands;
};

$scope.getNextFlavour = function(){
    if($scope.flavours.length  === $scope.flavourCount){
        $scope.measureCount = $scope.measureCount + 1;
        $scope.flavourCount = 0;
    }else{
        $scope.flavourCount = $scope.flavourCount + 1;  
    }
    $scope.totalBrands = $scope.flavours[$scope.flavourCount].TotalBrands;  
};
```

Comment: i didn't get you. can you explain in diff way. or show in code